# Property Changed Event using other entities

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I found an excellent post by Jaganathan Bantheswaran at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbd951/how-to-handle-property-changed-event-in-lightswitch-2011/

I understand the concept, but I'm having trouble with applying it using other entities. For example moving Diploma Percentage to it's own entity, and HS Percentage to it's own entity.

I have tried the following, but get an argument exception that the control DPercentage cannot be found.

```
        void CreateNewStudent_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("EntryMode"))
        {
            if (this.StudentProperty.EntryMode.Equals("LE"))
            {
                this.FindControl("DiplomaPercentage").IsVisible = true;
                this.FindControl("HSSPercentage").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("DPercentage").IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.FindControl("DiplomaPercentage").IsVisible = false;
                this.FindControl("HSSPercentage").IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: student entity]

[image: student screen]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that these lines executed just fine:

```
 this.FindControl("DiplomaPercentage").IsVisible = true;
 this.FindControl("HSSPercentage").IsVisible = false;
```

Then an exception is thrown on:

```
this.FindControl("DPercentage").IsVisible = false;
```

If this is the case, have you checked that DPercentage is indeed the name of your control? Because in the screen, DPercentage is the **Display name**. I have no way of verifying whether the control name is also DPercentage.

Hope this helps.